# Sort array of pairs by two different orders, without using built-in methods

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have a given array of pairs T = [[a1,b1],[a2,b2],...,[an,bn]] and I would like to sort it so that the elements b1,b2,...,bn are in ascending order and if some bs are equal sort 'a' elements in descending order

Example: for [1,6],[2,3],[5,7],[5,6],[2,5] the result should be like this:  [2,3],[2,5],[5,6],[1,6],[5,7]

The problem is that I can't use any built-in functions, methods etc.

At first I thought to use twice some stable sorting, but I also care about execution time, isn't there any faster way to do it?

Comment: Why can't you use built-in functions?

Comment: Is there any logical connection between values of `a` and values of `b`? Like e.g. opposite sides on a dice so [[1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 4]]? If that's not the case I don't think there is a better way as to sort values `a` and `b` independently from each other. If the value range is not to big and you deal with integers only like in your example you could use CountSort for both though. That way you would still end up with runtime of `2n = O(n)`, but even `2 O(n log n) = O(n log n)` when using e.g. merge sort would not be slow.

Comment: yeah there is connection - a and b are beggining and end of closed interval

Comment: sorry that could be unclear, i edited question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement any simple sorting algorithm like [InsertionSort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-insertion-sort/), but instead of direct comparison of pairs use function like this:

```
def less(p1, p2):
   if p1[1] < p2[1]:
       return True
   elif p1[1] > p2[1]:  
       return False
   else:
       return p1[0] > p2[0]
```

If list size is large, then apply faster algo with the same comparison function

So instead of something like:

```
 while j >=0 and key < T[j] :
```

you have to write:

```
while j >=0 and less(key, T[j]):
```